# How to "flatten" a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe `df` that looks as follows:

```
                                                 Expenses
date           manufacturer     department      
2021.01.03     Mercedes         Service          541
                                Sales            879
                                Marketing        134
2021.01.04     Mercedes         Service          471
                                Sales            193
                                Marketing        302
2021.01.05     Mercedes         Service          938
                                Sales            183
                                Marketing        193
```

Notice that `Expenses` is on a **higher level** than `date`, `manufacturer`, and `department`.

When I call `df.columns`, I see the following:

```
Index(['Expenses'], dtype='object)
```

I was expecting to see a list containing `Expenses`, `date`, `manufacturer`, and `department`.  Something as follows:

```
df.columns.values.tolist()
['Expenses', 'date', 'manufacturer', 'department']
<class 'list'>
```

How would I "flatten" this dataframe so that `Expenses`, `date`, `manufacturer`, and `department`  are all treated as **columns on the same level**?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The other labels are part of a multiindex. If I understand your expected output (sample would help) you just need to [reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

Comment: `df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(0)` or `df.to_flat_index()`

Comment: Hi, your table is not clear, could you put it in a better format? For what I can understand, it seems that 'date', 'manufacturer', 'department' are part of the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If 'date', 'manufacturer' and 'department'  are part of the index. This might help you:

`df = df.reset_index()`

Comment: Resetting the index brings everything on the same "level".  The problem is that if I call `df['manufacturer'].shape()`, I get a `KeyError: 'manufacturer'`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you need.

Comment: After resetting the index, I would be able to ACCESS all of the columns.  Currently, I am only able to access `Expenses`.  Calling `df['manufacter'].shape()` results in a `KeyError: 'manufacturer'`.  The other "columns" are not being treated as "columns".